# iOS : Cropping Image from Rotated ImageView

Tags: ios

How to crop a rectangle(red square in screen shot) of `UIImage` which is rotated as well as zoomed using UIScrollView.

The edges of `UIImageView` are hidden because of rotation(`UIImageView` Transformation). Please help.

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do all the complicated core graphics things or do a simple `UIView` screenshot. I vote for the easy solution: What you have to do is create a new view with the frame same as where that small rect lies. Then add the whole image view to that small view converting its frame so it looks the same. Then take the screenshot of the small view. After you are done simply put the image view back the way it was and remove the small view.

As this is still easier said then done here is some code to chew on (I did NOT test this so please correct the bugs if any after you succeed).

```
- (UIImage *)getScreenshotInRect:(CGRect)frame {
    UIImageView *theImageView; //your original image view

    UIView *backupSuperView = theImageView.superview; //backup original superview
    CGRect backupFrame = theImageView.frame; //backup original frame

    UIView *frameView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; //create new view where the image should be taken at
    frameView.clipsToBounds = YES; //not really necessery but can be usefull for cases like using corner radius
    [self addSubview:frameView];

    theImageView.frame = [theImageView.superview convertRect:theImageView.frame toView:frameView]; //set the new frame for the image view
    [frameView addSubview:theImageView];

    UIImage *toReturn = [self imageFromView:frameView]; //get the screenshot

    theImageView.frame = backupFrame; //reset the image view frame
    [backupSuperView addSubview:theImageView]; //reset the image view's superview

    [frameView removeFromSuperview];
    frameView = nil;

    return toReturn;
}
- (UIImage *)imageFromView:(UIView *)view {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, .0f);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return img;
}
```

I do hope this doesn't break because you have rotations. If that is the case I suggest you create another view on which the rotated image view lies and add this view to the small view.